# blogdown::serve_site() cannot render Rmd file

Tags: r, blogdown

When I ran `blogdown::serve_site()`, I get the below error.
Could you please help me understand this error and suggest a fix?

```
> library(blogdown)
> blogdown::serve_site()
Rendering content/post/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown.Rmd
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  function 'execLaterNative2' not provided by package 'later'
```

R version: 3.6.3

R-studio version: 1.3.1073

Comment: You could try the following: Update all your packages and then try again.

Comment: @SteffenMoritz- I tried your suggestion. It is still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed `blogdown` package directly from github and it worked fine.

```
remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```